# Function for counting letters in multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, textarea

I"m trying to create a function to use for multiple textareas for counting the letters inside and show them in the title.

Here is what i have got so far, I"m trying to pass the variables to the function:

```js
$('[name=messagetext]').keyup(countinput("[name=messagetext]", "#count_messagetext", "#000000"));
$('[name=messagetext]').keydown(countinput("[name=messagetext]", "#count_messagetext", "#000000"));

$('[name=abouttext]').keyup(countinput("[name=abouttext]", "#count_abouttext", "#000000"));
$('[name=abouttext]').keydown(countinput("[name=abouttext]", "#count_abouttext", "#000000"));

function countinput(name, countid, color) {
 var count = $(name).val().length;
 $(countid).text(count);
 if (count >= 170) {
  $(countid).css('color', '#ed7777');
  $(countid).css('font-weight', '600');
 } else {
  $(countid).css('color', color);
  $(countid).css('font-weight', '700');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">Message (<span id="count_messagetext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" name="messagetext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">About (<span id="count_abouttext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" name="abouttext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>
```

Comment: you can also add this in your textarea tag :    onkeyup="countinput(this, '#count_messagetext', '#000000')"

Comment: or add function(){} in keyup and keydown  like this one: $("[name=messagetext]").keyup(function(){countinput("[name=messagetext]", "#count_messagetext", "#000000")});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

What I changed is

- It auto detect the `<h3>` we have to change the color so you don't
  have to specify it each time

```js
$( object ).prev('h3')
```

- Keydown event trigger both instead of duplicating the same line for both id

```js
$('#messagetext, #abouttext').keydown
```

- Auto find the span that need to have the number of letter and so no need to specify an id for it

```js
$( object ).prev('h3').find('span').text(object.val().length);
```

So here is the code :

```js
$('#messagetext, #abouttext').keydown(function() {
  countinput($(this), 'black') 
});

function countinput(object, color) {

    $( object ).prev('h3').find('span').text(object.val().length);

 if (object.val().length >= 5) {   
    
  $( object ).prev('h3').css('color', 'red');
        
  $( object ).prev('h3').css('font-weight', '600');
 }
 else {
  $( object ).prev('h3').css('color', color);
   $( object ).prev('h3').css('font-weight', '700');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">Message (<span id="count_messagetext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" id="messagetext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">About (<span id="count_abouttext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" id="abouttext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a single event for this.

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown, keyup', function(){
 
 var name = $(this).attr('name');
 var countid = $('#count_' + name);
 var count = $(this).val().length;
 
 //Default Color
 var color = '#000000';
 
 //You can just replace the default color here.
 if(name == 'messagetext'){
  color = '#000000';
 }else if(name == 'abouttext'){
  color = '#000000';
 }
 
 if (count >= 170) {
  $(countid).css('color', '#ed7777');
  $(countid).css('font-weight', '600');
 } else {
  $(countid).css('color', color);
  $(countid).css('font-weight', '700');
 }
 $(countid).html(count);
 
});
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">Message (<span id="count_messagetext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" name="messagetext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.7rem; font-weight: 600; color: #414456;">About (<span id="count_abouttext" value="0">0</span>/100)</h3>
<textarea rows="4" maxlength="100" style="height: auto !important;" name="abouttext" type="text" placeholder="Write your own message"></textarea>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```